# Create instance of internet explorer working with visual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I am working on a project to automate login and form fillup of a booking website.The user enters all the required info into a windows form.When i fire the Go button there is an automatic login followed by form fillup(it's an autofill thing i am trying to).I dont want to use the inbuilt web browser of visual c# of which i can easily create new instances.
Now i can start up Internet explorer but i need to tell the PC what info to fill in what page.So i think i need to create an instance of Internet Explorer for every different page

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        IE.Navigate("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf");
        HtmlElementCollection inputs = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement field in inputs)
        {
            if (field.GetAttribute("name").Equals("j_username"))
            {
                field.SetAttribute("value", "username");
            }
            if (field.GetAttribute("name").Equals("j_password"))
            {
                field.SetAttribute("value", "password");
            }
        }
```

When i use a web browser object instead of IE everything is fine.However now i get a runtime error
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" in the getElemetsbytagname line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the login page load to be completed before you try pulling and setting the inputs, add this line of code

while (IE.Busy);

before

HtmlElementCollection inputs = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");